# Crashlytics found an invalid API key: @string/twitter_consumer_secret

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

When I installed **Firebase Crashlytics** in my project there was an error like this:

```
  Crashlytics found an invalid API key: @string/twitter_consumer_secret. 
  Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added 
  successfully! 
  Contact support@fabric.io for assistance.
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on fabric.properties like this:

`# Fabric properties file: app/fabric.properties
apiSecret=xxxexxcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
apiKey=xxxexxcxxxxxxexcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

REMOVE below code from AndroidManifest.xml:

`<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxax" />`

Refer Here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/working-in-teams.html

Comment: Have u added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

I my case the problem was that I was using a very old version of the `firebase-ui-auth` library:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
```

After I changed it to the more recent one the problem is gone:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
```

In general I'd recommend to review all your google/firebase libraries versions.